# DYLD/Darling - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, .app

I have been trying to run a MacOS X app on Ubuntu, so I resorted to Darling http://darlinghq.org.

I start it with,

```
dyld the_app.app/
```

But it returns:

```
dyld: Cannot execute binary file: dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/Versions/A/GameKit
```

There is a framework folder in the app file. Am I supposed to be moving something?

I haven't found anything about it while searching so I'm dumbfounded.

EDIT:
I tried setting the library variable to the `Resorses` folder in the .app file and the framework variable to the 
`Framework` folder inside, but it still said the same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust `DYLD_ROOT_PATH` or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (env vars).

Comment: To the folder the app is in?

Comment: Wherever the frameworks are. Also try `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH`.

Comment: I tried `export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH = "<filePath>"` but it didn't work. It returned `-bash: export: '=': not a valid identifier`. am I doing this wong

Comment: Remove the spaces. `export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH="<filePath>"`

Comment: I changed all of the DYLD env vars you suggested, but it is still erroring out with the same dyld message.